# Bridging virtual interface and real lan

Tags: debian, routing, iptables

I have to deal with this situation: a piece of software got hardcoded IP address (let assume it is being 196.10.10.100:20000) to which it binds a socket and sends TCP and UDP traffic to 196.10.10.9:20000 (hardcoded too). Problem is that for system to work there should be several instances of this software on separate different hosts. There is no chance to modify the software.

original setup was involving some kind of non-RFC compatible network hardware that was mapping MACs in first LAN into MACs in second LAN. Now it is required to emulate it without any extra network hardware - just a hot per instance of client and a host for server. There is (new) server software that expect to accept packets and respond, using separate NIC for each instance, IP addresses allowed to be in arbitrary subnets.

I do not see any problem with the server part, but there is now way that hosts with same IPs can be connected to server. I assume there is no problem with using system software to resolve it, but I don't know how to emulate an interface with required IP on client host and redirect traffic to server, to send traffic from server to client software (which would expect it coming from non-existing 196.10.10.9). I suppose that softawe should be run within  namespace container. I was told that bridging  it is possible using iptables, but all I know about that iptables is packet filter\NAT software.

I have partial solution, without DMZ and redirection of traffic to proper ip

```
ip netns add vn
ip link add v-eth0 type veth peer name v-local
ip link set v-local netns vn

ip addr add 196.10.10.1/24 dev v-eth0
ip netns exec vn ip addr add 196.10.10.100/24 dev v-local
ip link set v-eth0 up
ip netns exec vn ip link set v-local up

ip netns exec vn ip route add default via 196.10.10.1
echo 1 > /sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -F FORWARD
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 196.10.10.0/255.255.255.0 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o v-eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -i v-eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

This setup allows process in namespace container to access real network, but doesn't allow redirection I require.
Let assume that eth0 got IP 196.10.20.100 and server got IP 196.10.20.9. How I should modify the script above to be able

1) to redirect packets from 196.10.10.100 destinated to 196.10.10.9, so they would be sent to 196.10.20.9, and

2) to redirect packets, received by 196.10.20.100, to be sent to 10.10.10.100?

I changed v-eth0's address to 196.10.10.9/24:

```
ip addr add 196.10.10.9/24 dev v-eth0
```

And added prerouting and postrouting rules to replace source and destination for each direction, instead of standard masquerading:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -i v-eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 20000 -j DNAT --to-dest 196.10.20.9 
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 20000 -j SNAT --to-source 196.10.20.100 

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 20000 -j DNAT --to-dest 196.10.10.100
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o v-eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 20000 -j SNAT --to-source 196.10.10.9
```

Is that right and should it be enough? Using Wireshark I see packets going through the router from software inside the container, but it finds itself  being unable to send packets for some reason (no ICMP errors in Wireshark log though)

Comment: Why are you talking about MAC mapping, if the software only has _IP_ addresses hardcoded?

Comment: @grawity because original setup used multiple subnets with same IP adresses in each subnet ... whith were not visible externally as any interface thank to that, macs in each subnet was same too, but outside device was accepting packet with "fake" MAC with destination encoded into it, based on whith it was rerouting packets to appropriate interface. i have workaround for outer part already,different server software